# SVM packages that support data instances weighting in R

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I am looking for a SVM package in R that accepts specifying a weight for each instance of the data. I have found [e1071](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf) package, it provides a class weighting option with **class.weights** parameter, but it does not provide any option for instance weighting. I also found [wsvm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wSVM/wSVM.pdf) package, but neither it provides that functionality. I am looking for something like [libsvm-weights-3.17](https://github.com/claesenm/EnsembleSVM/tree/master/libsvm-weights-3.17) in R.

Comment: I found this when googling "kernlab observation weights": https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/personalized/versions/0.1.5/topics/weighted.ksvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this package: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=WeightSVM

It uses a modified version of 'libsvm' and is able to deal with instance weighting.

For example. You have simulated data (x,y)

```
x <- seq(0.1, 5, by = 0.05)
y <- log(x) + rnorm(x, sd = 0.2)
```

This is an unweighted SVM:

```
model1 <- wsvm(x, y, weight = rep(1,99))
```

[Blue dots is the unweighted SVM and do not fit the first instance well. We want to put more weights on the first several instances.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9qDd.png)

So we can use a weighted SVM:

```
model2 <- wsvm(x, y, weight = seq(99,1,length.out = 99))
```

[Green dots is the weighted SVM and fit the first instance better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgsQA.png)